# How to create metadata(JSON) of any file in ckan using java?

Tags: java, python, json, api, ckan

I have a file in the local system and I want to create a metadata of that file which includes:

```
{Filename, create date, update date, file format etc etc}
```

as a key value pair in JSON format. Next, I want to upload it in CKAN,(CKAN API call) so that I can finally see the file using the CKAN url. I already have CKAN host url with CKAN key.

Please can someone help me to write this script in Java? I am new to CKAN and its the first time try to do this but I am not able to. It will be helpful if someone can share sample piece of code to refer. I think it should just be an API call.

1.Below is python script for same work. But I want it to be done in java, please help..

```
metadata ={}
azure_urls=[]
for blob in urls:
    print(blob)
    for url in urls[blob]:
        print(url)
        r = requests.get(url,stream=True)
        file_name = url.split(“/”)[-1]
        with open(file_name, ‘wb’) as data:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024*1024):
                if chunk:
                    data.write(chunk)
        block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(path.join(container,blob),
                              data.name,
                              file_name ,
                              content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(‘./%s’ %url.split(“/”)[-1])[0]))
        print(‘uploading file to ‘+’‘+blob+' ‘+’in a ‘+ container)
        os.remove(data.name)
        download_url = block_blob_service.make_blob_url(path.join(container, blob),data.name)
        azure_urls.append(download_url)
    metadata[blob]= azure_urls
    metadata[‘Title’] = ‘Dbpedia’+‘-’+blob
    metadata[‘Publisher’] = ‘Name’
    metadata[‘Created’] = datetime.now().strftime(“%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S”)
    metadata[‘version’] = “2016-10"
    metadata[ “Container”] = container
    metadata[‘SourceType’] = [url.split(“.”)[-1] for url in azure_urls]
    print(metadata)
```

2. And below is ckanAPI call statement:

   ckan = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN(‘http://hostname’,‘key’ )

3.getting output in url as below:

```
{‘ontology’: [‘link1', ‘link2’], ‘Title’: ‘Dbpedia-ontology’, ‘Publisher’: ‘SiddarthaP’, ‘Created’: ‘2017-08-03 00:55:22’, ‘version’: ‘2016-10’, ‘Container’: ‘dbpedia’, ‘SourceType’: [‘owl’, ‘nt’]}
```

Comment: You should add the code you have tried so we can help you

Comment: @CristiánRamón-Cortés added python script of same work. Not able to write java script..Please check and help

Comment: There is something unclear for me: do you need it in Java or JavaScript?

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that what you are trying to do is to process some information in a given format and upload it to CKAN. I am not sure that the code you provided in `Python` does what you expect (i.e. the URLs are shared among all the blobs, not accumulated for each one) and it does not upload anything either.

This said, using the JAKAN API v0.4 you can write a similar code that:

- Creates a CKAN secure client
- Processes the information you receive from your other service
- Creates a JSON representation of the metaData
- Uploads it to CKAN

The code:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");


public static void processUrls(String[] blobs, Map<String, String[]> urls) {
    CkanClient cc = new CheckedCkanClient("HOSTNAME", "key");

    // Process each blob
    for (String dsName : blobs) {
        System.out.println("DATASET: " + dsName);

        // Process all the available URLS of the same blob
        List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        String publisherName;
        String container;
        for (String url : urls.get(blob)) {
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
            String[] urlFields = url.split("/");
            String fileName = urlFields[urlFields.length - 1];

            System.out.println(" - Resource " + fileName + " with URL " + url);

            urls.add(url);
        }

        // Construct the JSON metadata
        JSONObject metaData = createMetaData(dsName, urls, publisherName, container);
        System.out.println("METADATA: ");
        System.out.println(metaData.toJSONString());

        // Upload to CKAN
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        CkanDataset cd = objectMapper.readValue(metaData, CkanDataset.class);
        CkanDataset createdDataset = cc.createDataset(cd);
    }
}

private JSONObject createMetaData(String dsName, List<String> urls, String publisherName, String container) {
    JSONArray metaDataUrls = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray urlTypes = new JSONArray();
    for (String url : urls) {
        metaDataUrls.put(url);
        String[] urlFields = url.split(".");
        urlTypes.put(urlFields[urlFields.length - 1]);
    }

    JSONObject metaData = new JSONObject();
    metaData.put(dsName, metaDataUrls);
    metaData.put("Title", "Dbpedia-" + dsName);
    metaData.put("Publisher", publisherName);
    metaData.put("Created", FORMAT.format(new Date()));
    metaData.put("version", "2016-10");
    metaData.put("Container", container);
    metaData.put("SourceType", urlTypes);

    return metaData;
}
```

Comment: There is an API for ckan... Named - JACKAN

Comment: There is more than one Java API for CKAN... See my updated answer using JAKAN. However, you should state more clearly your question since it is hard to know in which format is the information you are trying to upload.

Comment: Thanku Cristian, this updated code seems useful to me... Will use this and work further...